# How to count no. of occurrences for each row with arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

(Google Sheets) Hi, I need to create a formula that counts the number of occurrences of a specific fruit for each row. I want the value of Mango Occurrences to appear in column D.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Sweetest** | **Healthiest** | **Juciest** | **Mango Occurrences** | 2 |
| 2 | Mango | Lemon | Mango |  |  |
| 3 | Mango | Lemon | Watermelon |  |  |

Formula in cell D1: `=arrayformula({"Mango Occurrences", COUNTIF(A1:C1, "Mango")})`

The problem is that this formula counts the occurrences of mango for only the specified row, and surprisingly reflects this value in column E. How do I change the formula such that the mango occurrences for each row is reflected, preferably in column D? Also, due to the nature of the task, the `=arrayformula` function can't be removed. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Rework the question and the question's header + tags. `ARRAYFORMULA()` is a Google Sheets only function so if it's a must to use that function you can't use Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In D1 you can try

```
=ArrayFormula({"Mango Occurrences"; IF(LEN(A2:A), MMULT(--(A2:C="Mango"), transpose(column(A1:C1)^0)),)})
```

and see if that works?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="Mango", ROW(B2:D), )), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1"), "offset 2", ))
```

[image]